# NullPointerException in LibGDX Android project

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, libgdx

I've been developing a 2D game (using LibGDX) and I've been getting crashes on SOME devices during my Alpha test. From the pre-launch report, the issue is as follows:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music.setLooping(boolean)' on a null object reference
>
> > at com.bonbon.lubyjump.game.Game.initialiseSounds(Game.java:151)
> >
> > at com.bonbon.lubyjump.game.Game.loadSounds(Game.java:147)
> >
> > at com.bonbon.lubyjump.game.Game.create(Game.java:102)
> >
> > atcom.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:311)
> >
> > at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1519)
> >
> > at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)

From what I understand, `setLooping()` would throw the above error only if there was no "Theme.wav" audio file. But the fact that some devices are running without any crashes seems to indicate that the audio file DOES exist. Is there anything I might've overlooked that could be generating the `NullPointerException`? I haven't been able to recreate the error on any virtual devices in Android Studio.

```
private void loadSounds() {
    try {
        themeSong = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("Theme.wav"));
        gamePlaySong = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("Gameplay.wav"));
        jumpSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("Jump.wav"));
        fartSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("Fart.wav"));
        gameOverSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("GameOver.wav"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    initialiseSounds();
}

private void initialiseSounds(){
    themeSong.setLooping(true);  //This line causes the error
    themeSong.setVolume(soundVolume);
    themeSong.play();
    gamePlaySong.setVolume(soundVolume);
}
```

Comment: It is highly recommended to post code as formatted text in your post instead of an image.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: The error is because themeSong is null. You print the stack trace with `e.printStackTrace()`, include that here as well to see what the original error you caught was.

Comment: @TylerV For themeSong to be null, that wouldn't that mean that Music file was missing? If so, it should've crashed on ALL devices. But its only crashing on a select few. Also, I've included the stack trace, but it doesn't seem like it was printed from `e.printStackTrace()` (Since `initialiseSounds()`was called)

Comment: You should see some error message printed earlier from the printStackTrace above the fatal exception. Alternately, you could remove the try-catch to see what is thrown there.

Comment: @TylerV I ran it without the try-catch. Once again, the virtual devices ran without any issues. However, the pre-launch report still had crashes with the error being identified as `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading audio file: Theme.wav
Note: Internal audio files must be placed in the assets directory.` I did recheck my assets folder and the the audio files were present so I'm still confused about how this is happening. Could it be that the crashing devices don't support **.wav** files?

Comment: That's odd, I'm not sure what the solution is. If you post the pre-launch emulator details about which ones crash and which don't (e.g. device type and android version) maybe someone else will have an idea?

Comment: @TylerV Turns out that I was right about the devices not being able to play **.wav** files. I converted the audio files to **mp3** and viola- no more crashes! Thanks for your help btw :)

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may have encountered the same problem, I found out that certain devices were crashing because they could not process **wav** files, which was the format I used for my audio files. Once I converted them to **mp3**, the issue was resolved and all devices ran without crashing.